# Mounting a folder that is on a Time Capsule

Tags: networking, afp

We don't so much have a file server in our little office, so I thought we could maybe use an Apple Time Capsule (which I already have).

I'm having trouble mounting it, with the following:

```
mount -t afp afp://10.0.1.1 /Volumes/test
```

This error is returned:

```
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 22, errno is 2
```

I'm not sure whats going on, I tried the `-i` (interactive) parameter and it prompts me for my username and password, and even though they are correct the same error occurs. Same is true if I put my correct `username:password` after the protocol in the address as well.

Is this any different then mounting any other network drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `-v` to get the verbose output, post it here if you need more help with the output of that.

Did you mean to put a space between the IP and the Volume path? I don't think that's supposed to be there :)

Comment: you win... dude I was totally not even thinking about it. That gave me the output I needed. Everything worked as expected I just had a configuration problem on my end.

Comment: No problem, sometimes it's the simple things that you never think of :)

Answer (score 0):

On 10.11.3 the following AFP mount was working:

```
mount -v -o automounted -t afp afp://user:password@File-Server.local/${ShareName} /Volumes/${ShareName}
```

On 10.11.3 the following SMB mount was working:

```
mount -v -o automounted,soft -t smbfs smb://user:password@File-Server.local/${ShareName} /Volumes/${ShareName}
```